# Transforming matrix diagonals to ragged array?

Tags: math, matrix

I'm trying to come up with a non brute-force solution to the following problem. Given a matrix of arbitrary size:

```
[6  0  3  5]
[3  7  1  4]
[1  4  8  2]
[0  2  5  9]
```

Transform its diagonals to a list of vectors, like so:

```
(0)
(1, 2)
(3, 4, 5)
(6, 7, 8, 9)
(0, 1, 2)
(3, 4)
(5)
```

(Working from bottom left to top right in this example)

Is there an elegant way to do this short of iterating up the left column and across the top row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just write a little function to transform the vector indices into matrix indices.

Say the matrix is `NxN` square, then there will be `2N-1` vectors; if we number the vectors from `0` to `2N-2`, element `k` of vector `n` will be at row `max(N-1-n+k,k)` and column `max(n+k-N+1,k)` (or in reverse, the matrix element at row `i`, column `j` will be element `min(i,j)` of vector `N-1+j-i`). Then whenever you need to access an element of a vector, just convert the coordinates from `k,n` to `i,j` (that is, convert vector indices to matrix indices) and access the appropriate element of the matrix. Instead of actually having a list of vectors, you'll wind up with something that *emulates* a list of vectors, in the sense that it can give you any desired element of any vector in the list - which is really just as good. (Welcome to duck typing ;-)

If you're going to access every element of the matrix, though, it might just be quicker to iterate, rather than doing this computation every time.

Answer (score 1):

(non-checked code)
Something like this (java code):

```
// suppose m is the matrix, so basically an int[][] array with r rows and c columns
// m is an int[rows][cols];

List result = new ArrayList(rows + cols - 1);
for (int i = 0; i < (rows + cols - 1))
{
  int y;
  int x;
  if (i < rows)
  {
    x = 0;
    y = rows - i - 1;
  }
  else
  {
    x = i - rows + 1;
    y = 0;
  }
  Vector v = new Vector();
  while (y < rows && x < cols)
  {
    y++;
    x++;
    v.add(new Integer(m[y][c]));
  }
  result.add(v);
}
// result now contains the vectors you wanted
```

**Edit:** i had x and y mixed up, corrected now.

Comment: Suggestion: use ArrayList again instead of the Vector inside the loop. (Also, this could be updated to modern Java using generics and autoboxing)

Comment: @David: i would use ArrayLists, but the orig post was talking about Vectors :) and (still) not everyone uses java 1.5+

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica:

```
m = {{6, 0, 3, 5}, 
     {3, 7, 1, 4}, 
     {1, 4, 8, 2}, 
     {0, 2, 5, 9}};

Table[Diagonal[m, i], {i, 1 - Length@m, Length@m[[1]] - 1}]
```

Which gives a list of the i'th diagonals where the 0th diagonal is the main diagonal, i = -1 gives the one below it, etc.  In other words, it returns:

```
{{0}, {1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9}, {0, 1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5}}
```

Of course using the built-in `Diagonal` function is kind of cheating.  Here's an implementation of `Diagonal` from scratch:

```
(* Grab the diagonal starting from element (i,j). *)
diag0[m_,i_,j_] := Table[m[[i+k, j+k]], {k, 0, Min[Length[m]-i, Length@m[[1]]-j]}]

(* The i'th diagonal -- negative means below the main diagonal, positive above. *)
Diagonal[m_, i_] := If[i < 0, diag0[m, 1-i, 1], diag0[m, 1, i+1]]
```

The `Table` function is basically a for loop that collects into a list.  For example,

```
Table[2*i, {i, 1, 5}]
```

returns `{2,4,6,8,10}`.